# Found more than one class "connection" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'BiocGenerics'

Tags: r, namespaces, connection, shiny, bioconductor

I have a shiny app which runs a bunch of packages including some from bioconductor.

After a recent update of all used packages, there are lots of warnings:

> Found more than one class "connection" in cache; using the first, from
>   namespace 'BiocGenerics'

Anyone has solutions to suppress the warnings?

Comment: Related [issue](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/issues/48) that was resolved by switching to `jsonlite` from `RJSONIO`. However, this didn't work for me. So could bioconductor gurus please stand up, please stand up.